# Create new column in sql query from CASE expression

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have following sql query:

```
SELECT score,
    case when index_1<1 THEN target= 0.1+0.01*LEAST(index_1,index_2) ELSE score
END as new_score
FROM new_df
```

the variable "target" is a new variable that I am trying to create inside my query.
as in this query, it returns me an error> no such column: target

How to create this variable inside this query?

Comment: What do you want to do with this variable? Or, in other words, what are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Luuk what do u mean? I want to use it feature. First I want to create it using this formula in my query

Comment: @Luuk if you want to know what project am i doing, I can email you dataframe and problem that needs to be solved

Comment: Why not:  `case when index_1<1 THEN 0.1+0.01*LEAST(index_1,index_2) ELSE score
END as target`? or  `case when index_1<1 THEN target= 0.1+0.01*LEAST(index_1,index_2) END as target`  (notice 2nd has no else)

Comment: @Krish: no thanks, I hope you can manage to do your own work. .

Comment: Those are column (expressions) not "variables"

Comment: Is you new virtual column (not variable, SQL doesn't have those) supposed to be called "new_score", or "target"?